# QGIS's Difference function inconsistently applied in complicated shapefile

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, I'm using Difference (under the Geoprocessing menu) to subtract a complicated shapefile with plenty of features from another complicated shapefile.

For 90% of the features, it works correctly. But for some, it ends up deleting the underlying feature altogether, instead of returning the difference -- even though the "Difference" feature didn't entirely cover up the underlying feature.

Here's an example:

The selected feature on the base layer.
[image: Selected county]

The soon-to-be-Difference layer, in pink. Note that the selected feature is not wholly obscured by the difference layer, so it should show up in the final result.
[image]

The resulting shapefile. Note that the previously selected area is entirely blank (along with a good deal of the map that shouldn't be, as well.)
[image]

Comment: You should always evaluate shapefiles for topological integrity when they don't function as expected.  Many times the issue is an incorrectly wrapped polygon ring.

Comment: @arm5077 - Sometimes the version of QGIS matters (i.e. older versions of QGIS performs geoprocessing operations correctly compared to the latest versions). You could upload your shapefiles to a public server so that others could test your data.